# How did I make this screen appear?

Tags: macos

This is a pretty general question, and I'm sorry I don't have a screenshot for you.

First, some specs: I am running OSX Lion on a MacMini with a Magic Mouse.

I had a screen appear and I'm not sure what it was or how it appeared. All my windows faded out and there was a list of files (and folders perhaps) listed above the dock station. This was not mission control or launchpad, I know that much. It also wasn't whatever the screen is that I get when I two-finger swipe to the right (with the calculator, clock, weather and other widgets).

If it helps at all, when it happend I was attempting to open my DropBox folder. I am often switching between a Windows PC and my Mac. I've been on my Windows computer lately and am used to opening DropBox by double-clicking the icon in the task bar. It was somewhere around that time this screen appeared. It disappeared when I clicked anywhere outside the file icons - which I unfortunately did pretty quickly.

If there is any other information I can give to possibly identify this screen, just let me know.

Comment: It's likely a folder of documents in your dock. If you right click on the folders that are in your dock, it will show a stack or grid option as well as let you experiment to see if that was the sort of gray window with documents or folders arranged in a grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you probably activated the "Application Windows" feature of Mission Control (previously Exposé) in an app that didn't have any windows open.

It looks like this if you have no windows in that app open:
[image: Application Windows Exposé]

The list of files are recently opened files in that application (in this case, TextEdit).

How you opened it depends on your particular setup. You can set a keyboard shortcut for it in System Preferences under Mission Control, but I think there are also gestures. I don't have a Magic Mouse or Trackpad with gesture support handy, so I can't confirm exactly what may have activated it for you. Look through the Mouse panel in System Preferences for any reference to Exposé or "Show Application Windows" or similar for an idea of what exactly activated it.

Comment: +10 for mind reading if this is the solution!

Comment: This is exactly what happened. I'll have to look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, for what its worth, Control+Down Key seemed to be the combination I must have hit somehow without realizing it. I could have sworn it was with the mouse... /shrug. You are certainly a mind reader.